# How to return a file from Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5

every  time I run this block

```
Route::get('myass',function(){

    return view("index");
});
```

It shows index file cannot be found but its already there
any help?

Answer (score 1):

Using method `view` you are trying to return parsed content of `resources/views/index.blade.php` or `resources/views/index.php`. It seems that you put your file into wrong directory or it has different extension.

Comment: no i rechecked it 3-4 times still showing this error

Comment: Check that the webserver has at least read permissions on the file.